# request.getHeader("referer"); value is getting null

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

In my webapp I'm opening (Browser: **IE**) a link using `onclick="this.form.target='_target';return true;"`. Because of https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/178066 this IE issue referer value is becoming **null** after loading the second page.

I am handling **null** referer values inside `doFilter` method, for **null referer** values I am redirecting to some kinda error page.

So I want to restrict referer from becoming null when I click this link, is there any solution for that?

Comment: You should not rely on this header anyway. If you really need to know the origin, pass it explicitly.

Comment: I know that referer can easily be spoofed , but I am looking for a solution with this scenario only, if it is possible.